# Error "bad magic number" al cifrar/descifrar utilizando OpenSSL

Tags: linux, openssl

Estoy utilizando actualmente la versión "OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019"

Para cifrar utilizo:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -pass file:llave.enc -in entrada.tar.gz -out salida.cif
```

y para descifrar el fichero:

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -pbkdf2 -d -pass file:llave.enc -in salida.cif -out entrada.tar.gz
```

El error que devuelve es:

> bad magic number

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Debía ser un error del fichero "llave.enc". Ahora me funciona perfectamente sin aplicar ningún cambio a lo publicado anteriormente :O